# aws python 3.8 lambda + async sqlalchemy 2.0.10, asyncpg 0.28.0

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, sqlalchemy, asyncpg

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession

engine_async = create_async_engine(
    "postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:password@host_name.rds.amazonaws.com/postgres")

def get_data(event, context): # this is the lambda handler
    return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(get_data_async(event, context))

async def get_datas_async(event, context):
    org_id = event['org_id']
    async_session = sessionmaker(bind=engine_async, future=True, class_=AsyncSession)
    async with async_session() as session1, async_session() as session2, async_session() as session3:
        users_count_query = select(func.count(User.user_id)).filter_by(org_id=org_id)
        org_name_query = select(Organization.name).filter_by(org_id=org_id)
        other_data_query = select(
            func.count(Transaction.transaction_id).label('transactions_count'),
            func.sum(Transaction.total_cost).label('total_cost'),
            func.sum(Transaction.total_time).label('total_time')).where(Transaction.org_id == org_id)

        tasks = [
            session1.execute(users_count_query),
            session2.execute(other_data_query),
            session3.execute(org_name_query)
        ]
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        userss_count, data, org_name = results
        data = data.fetchone()
        uesrs_count = users_count.scalar_one()
        org_name = org_name.scalar_one()

        return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "users_count": users_count,
            "transactions_count": data.transactions_count,
            "total_cost": 0 if not data.total_cost else data.total_cost,
            "total_time": data.total_time,
            "org_name": org_name,
        }
```

I get this error:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Method 'close()' can't be called here; method '_connection_for_bind()' is already in progress and this would cause an unexpected state change to <SessionTransactionState.CLOSED: 5>",
    "errorType": "IllegalStateChangeError",
    "stackTrace": [
        "  File \"/var/task/app.py\", line 131, in get_data\n    return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(get_data_async(event, context))\n",
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py\", line 616, in run_until_complete\n    return future.result()\n",
        "  File \"/var/task/app.py\", line 175, in get_data_async\n    return {\n",
        "  File \"/var/task/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/session.py\", line 859, in __aexit__\n    await asyncio.shield(task)\n",
        "  File \"/var/task/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/session.py\", line 840, in close\n    await greenlet_spawn(self.sync_session.close)\n",
        "  File \"/var/task/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py\", line 154, in greenlet_spawn\n    result = context.switch(*args, **kwargs)\n",
        "  File \"/var/task/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py\", line 2382, in close\n    self._close_impl(invalidate=False)\n",
        "  File \"/var/task/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py\", line 2424, in _close_impl\n    transaction.close(invalidate)\n",
        "  File \"<string>\", line 2, in close\n",
        "  File \"/var/task/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py\", line 121, in _go\n    raise sa_exc.IllegalStateChangeError(\n"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need three async sessions?

Comment: Yes, because using one session causes this error. Not sure why it's still happening with separate sessions. https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/9312

Comment: Maybe check https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/_modules/examples/asyncio/gather_orm_statements.html

Answer (score 0):

solution and explanation are here: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/9312